# Netuix and p13n dependencies missing

Tags: java, oracle, maven, weblogic

I have to recreate the local environment of a Maven project. Along other dependencies, it manually pulls some Oracle libraries from a local installation of WebLogic, using `truezip-maven-plugin` and `maven-install-plugin`, to put them into `.m2`.

For example, in my `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <configuration>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-weblogic-libs</id>
            <configuration>
                <files>
                    <file>
                        <source>${WL_HOME}/wlserver/server/lib/consoleapp/APP-INF/lib/p13n_system.jar</source>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/temp/com.bea.p13n/p13n-app-lib-base</outputDirectory>
                    </file>
                </files>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <packaging>jar</packaging>
        <generatePom>true</generatePom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-com-bea-p13n-app-lib-base-p13n-system</id>
            <configuration>
                <file>
                    ${project.build.directory}/temp/com.bea.p13n/p13n-app-lib-base/p13n_system.jar
                </file>
                <groupId>com.bea.p13n.p13n-app-lib-base</groupId>
                <artifactId>p13n_system</artifactId>
                <version>10.3.6</version>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>install</phase>            
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This works fine.

But the project requires other `.jars`, that don't seem to exist. Specifically, `p13n_app.jar`, `p13n_ejb.jar` and `netuix.jar` (all under `com.bea` domain). The project is setup to connect to `maven.oracle.com` through `settings.xml`. I tried searching for a manual download of these `.jars` but without success. 
 This is all I could find:

- Manually browsing the Maven repository

  https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/bea/

  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bea.p13n

Dead end, since neither `netuix` nor `p13n` packages exist (even though there are results in `mvnrepository.com`).

- Manually browsing other repositories, like:

  http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/c/com.bea.htm

Again, dead end for the same reason.

```
https://maven.oracle.com/com/bea/p13n/p13n-app-lib-base/p13n_app/10.3.6/p13n_app-10.3.6.pom
```

This is the link Maven tries to connect to download the dependency. It says `Not found`

```
http://nexus.emergya.es/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;quick~com.bea.p13n
```

It actually has some results, but when clicking the Download button it leads to [this page](http://nexus.emergya.es/nexus/service/local/artifact/maven/redirect?r=nexus-nuxeo&g=com.bea.p13n&a=ejb&v=10.3.2&e=jar).

- Installing a different WebLogic package. I installed a development version, so I thought it could miss something, but even after installing the standard WebLogic they are missing
- Browsing existing WebLogic installments, like test environments from other projects

Should I keep searching for these libraries or are they deprecated? Can I extract these libraries from a `war` already build with it? They seem to have been deleted anywhere. In this case I should search for a newer library (with the risk of incompatibilities with the code already written). Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was pointing to a wrong WebLogic product! I discovered that the native `pom.xml` of the project has to work with WebLogic Portal 10.3.6 instead of WebLogic Server 10.3.6! It took me some time to find out a link to download this Portal (since it's in EOL) but here it is:

1. Go to [this link](https://edelivery.oracle.com/osdc/faces/SoftwareDelivery)
2. Prompt `WebLogic Portal` (do NOT click on the suggestion, either it will show a lot more stuff)
3. Oracle WebLogic Portal 10.3.6.0.0, download it
4. It will download an `.exe` that will download the `.zip` wherever you want
5. Extract
6. Run the `.jar` with Java 7 and follow the guided installation procedure

It will contain everything, both `p13n` and `netuix` libraries, plus an installation of WebLogic Server!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the solution won't be easy. The libraries you're looking for have probably disappeared from the Oracle Maven repository. It happens quite often that old Oracle libraries or plugins for jDeveloper are removed. I had the same problem with the Oracle WebCenter plugin for JDeveloper 11g. The only solution was to recover these files from another computer.

I've unpacked and searched recursively all jars from WebLogic installation 10.3.6, and definitely the libraries you mentioned aren't there, neither in JDeveloper nor in Integrated WebLogic. Which makes sense since you have said that the project connects to maven.oracle.com for these dependencies.

I've connected to Oracle Maven, and these libraries don't exist there anymore. They were quite old, so they were probably deleted.

I see a few possible workarounds:

1. Locate the war of the built project and unpack the libraries. I don't know what this project is, but if these are not WebLogic libraries but dependencies, they should be in war (or ear).
2. Maybe someone has configured the whole environment for this project so you can copy libraries.
3. If you have paid support, you can create a ticket to Oracle.
4. Try to get help on the Oracle forum at https://community.oracle.com. Maybe you'll find someone who can help you.
5. Check if you really need these libraries. Maybe if you exclude them from the pom, everything will work. If problem happens during deployment, maybe it's enough to add missing libraries. Trying newer versions of these libraries if some are available is also possible.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Probably I got an idea. The native configuration pointed to `${WL_HOME}/wlportal_10.3`, but we have `${WL_HOME}/wlserver`. Maybe I just downloaded the wrong WebLogic product.. I hope so. Sadly I need them because there are a couple of imports..

Comment: Indeed! Solved the problem. Thank you again for your help! Posting the answer asap